# Why does fdisk prefer 512 byte sector size even when the physical sector size of the block device is 4096?

Tags: fdisk

I have a disk with 4096 byte sectors:

```
# cat /sys/class/block/sda/queue/physical_block_size
4096
#
```

For some reason, `fdisk` prefers to show the information about the disk using 512 byte sectors:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500DM002-1BD14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d98d6

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 976773167 976771120 465.8G 83 Linux
```

Just out of curiosity, why does `fdisk` prefer to operate with 512 byte sector sizes? I'm using `fdisk` version `2.33.1`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because your disk advertises a 512-byte logical sector size:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

You should be able to confirm this:

```sh
$ cat /sys/class/block/sda/queue/logical_block_size
512
```

The consequence is that sectors are addressed as 512-byte sectors, not 4096-byte sectors, so `fdisk` manipulates the former (and checks alignment with the latter).

Comment: Otherwise known as 512e because the drive emulates a 512 byte sector size for compatibility with older operating systems, even though it really uses 4k.